# !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor' error

Tags: python, opencv

```
# load our serialized face detector model from disk
print("[INFO] loading face detector model...")
prototxtPath = os.path.sep.join([args["face"], "deploy.prototxt"])
weightsPath = os.path.sep.join([args["face"],
    "res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.caffemodel"])
net = cv2.dnn.readNet(prototxtPath, weightsPath)

# load the face mask detector model from disk
print("[INFO] loading face mask detector model...")
model = load_model(args["model"])

# load the input image from disk, clone it, and grab the image spatial
# dimensions
image = cv2.imread(args["image"])
orig = image.copy()
(h, w) = image.shape[:2]

# construct a blob from the image
blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(image, 1.0, (300, 300),
    (104.0, 177.0, 123.0))

# pass the blob through the network and obtain the face detections
print("[INFO] computing face detections...")
net.setInput(blob)
detections = net.forward()

# loop over the detections
for i in range(0, detections.shape[2]):
    # extract the confidence (i.e., probability) associated with
    # the detection
    confidence = detections[0, 0, i, 2]

    # filter out weak detections by ensuring the confidence is
    # greater than the minimum confidence
    if confidence > args["confidence"]:
        # compute the (x, y)-coordinates of the bounding box for
        # the object
        box = detections[0, 0, i, 3:7] * np.array([w, h, w, h])
        (startX, startY, endX, endY) = box.astype("int")

        # ensure the bounding boxes fall within the dimensions of
        # the frame
        (startX, startY) = (max(0, startX), max(0, startY))
        (endX, endY) = (min(w - 1, endX), min(h - 1, endY))

        # extract the face ROI, convert it from BGR to RGB channel
        # ordering, resize it to 224x224, and preprocess it
        face = image[startY:endY, startX:endX]
        face = cv2.cvtColor(face, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        face = cv2.resize(face, (224, 224))
        face = img_to_array(face)
        face = preprocess_input(face)
        face = np.expand_dims(face, axis=0)
```

File "detect_mask_image.py", line 76, in mask_image
face = cv2.cvtColor(face, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'

Error occurs even though image is read
I made sure that the image is not None
There is no problem with path
Other images work well, but only this image does not work

Comment: "only this image does not work" which image?

Comment: Among the files that I have, other files in .jpg are executed, but when I run some files including this image file I want to run, this error appears

Comment: In that case, `face = image[startY:endY, startX:endX]` must be giving you an empty image.